# is it possible to force a(n embedded) JVM to only execute certain digitally signed apps?

Tags: java, embedded, digital-signature

A bit of a noob-who-tries-to-get-a-glimpse-of-something-without-making-homeworks-first question...

Suppose I'd like to include a JVM on a closed source O.S./hardware to be able to provide extended functionalities to customers with addon java applets, and that I'd want to be the only available source to develop and sell addon apps... then is it feaseable to easily implement such a mechanism by simply forcing embedded JVM to only allow execution of apps signed with my digital sign?

In other words I'd just like to know if this is an easy to implement, already proven to work, widely accepted path or just plain BS (for reasons you are free to not tell!) :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Adding my own answer to get feedback on the following solution, which seems to be the most fitting with my question:*

Could Java ***system* policy file** be the answer?

As far as I can understand from reading the documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html you can basically implement code execution permission policy in 2 ways:

1) implementing and extending permission policy at runtime (what @chrylis refers to).

2) using a default system policy file (java.home\lib\security\java.policy)

The second approach seems easier to implement and kind of more "static" which is a good thing given my use-case because I only need JVM to check that digital sign of app is mine to allow it to run, and will never ever need to extend this policy in any possible way.

So I am not sure yet but given my prerequisites this approach might be what I was looking for in my question... If you have any thoughts just add them, thanks.

Comment: care to share reason for downvote or you'd rather prefer being anonymous?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're wanting is [class signing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/). The startup code for your application can install a `SecurityManager` to ensure that only classes signed by keys matching some particular criteria can be loaded.

Comment: mm I'll look into it.. but then, why wouldn't be just enough to use jar signing capabilities if I am talking about an embedded JVM with hard-coded unchangeable options to only allow execution of apps with given digital-sign ? (hope it makes sense..)

Comment: You theoretically could do that, but it sounds like a lot more effort than just using a regular JVM. After all, you don't really care about whether people run other Java applications, just what code is allowed to run as part of yours.

Comment: wait, hmm, are you sure that providing a JVM with a kind of a bootstrap CSV digital signs to be read before every run of a java -jar something.jar command is going to be a big effort to implement? I am not a java dev, but it really doesn't sound that big effort? Couldn't it be just matter of some env. variables?

Comment: Could policy files be the answer to my question? Check out the link in my self-answer..